# getting array values without foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is there any way to get all values in one array without using foreach loops, in this example?

```
<?php 
$foo = array(["type"=>"a"], ["type"=>"b"], ["type"=>"c"]);
```

The output I need is `array("a", "b", "c")`

I could accomplish it using something like this

```
$stack = [];

foreach($foo as $value){
  $stack[] = $value["type"];
}

var_dump($stack);
```

But, I am looking for options that does not involve using foreach loops.

Comment: Do you want to use for loops?

Comment: @magnetronnie even worse :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.5+, you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column), like so:

```
$result = array_column($foo, 'type');
```

If you want an array with numeric indices, use:

```
$result = array_values(array_column($foo, 'type'));
```

If you're using a previous PHP version and can't upgrade at the moment, you can use the [Userland implementation of `array_column()`](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) function written by the same author.

Alternatively, you could also use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map). This is basically the same as a loop except that the looping is not explicitly shown.

```
$result = array_map(function($arr) {
   return $arr['type'];
}, $foo);
```

Comment: Sadly I am not using 5.5 Which I should be.

Comment: `array_values()` isn't required here as `array_column()` will return desired array

Comment: @AlmaDo: I'm aware. I just thought maybe the OP wanted to get an array with numeric indices.

Comment: 1. link is broken. 2. It's much better to update PHP than using external lib just because of one function

Comment: array_map is a bit similar to looping imho. I was looking something along by combining `each()` or `array_values()` I guess its not possible. Thanks anyway

Comment: @AlmaDo: 1. I was typing it from memory and made a typo :D It's been fixed, thanks! 2. I wouldn't call it a library. It's just a simple function. Take a look at the [code](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php#L31) if you want. I agree with you that an upgrade is always preferable. But for some folks, a quick upgrade is not *always* possible. ;)

Comment: @iOi It's okay! No hard feelings there. I'm glad you solved the problem at hand, nonetheless ;)

Comment: @AmalMurali Feel free to jump on board [on the next question if you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761727/getting-mysql-column-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 5):

Either use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) for PHP 5.5:

```
$foo = array(["type"=>"a"], ["type"=>"b"], ["type"=>"c"]);
$result = array_column($foo, 'type');
```

Or use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) for previous versions:

```
$result = array_map(function($x)
{
   return $x['type'];
}, $foo);
```

Note: The loop will still be performed, but it will be hidden inside the aforementioned functions.