# getting mysql column from the command line

Tags: mysql, sql

I am accessing mysql from cmd, and I want to get all rows from a specific table, but I can't find the exact command to do so.

Example:

```
SHOW DATABSES    #shows all available databases;
CONNECT TEST_DB  #I connect to  test_db
SHOW TABLES      #shows all tables.
```

What Is missing is how to only see the columns from a specific table.

if I do `SELECT * FROM table_test` it displays all results instead of just the columns

Comment: Why don't you use `DESCRIBE table_test`?

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks! Answer it to get my vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for:

```
DESCRIBE table_test;
```

which is same as

```
EXPLAIN table_test;
```

See reference in [MySQL - 13.8.1 DESCRIBE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html) which links to [MySQL - 13.8.1 EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).

Comment: Beaten to the punch. +1 - This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select a database:
   `USE YOUR_DB;`
2. To show your tables
   `SHOW TABLES;`
3. To show columns and rows of a table
   `DESC YOUR_TABLE;`
4. access a specific field
   `SELECT YOUR_COLUMN FROM YOUR_TABLE;`

   ---

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).